# Convert a string to date format and retrieve the week number

Tags: mysql, string, date

I have date of the format `15-Nov-20`. I want to convert it into date format of the MySQL table (yyyy-mm-dd) using query before inserting the data into the table and want to get the week and year separately of that date. I have tried the following query:

```
SELECT  STR_TO_DATE('15-Nov-20', '%Y-%m-%d') FROM table
```

But this returns `NULL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format string is incorrect (see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)). For your sample data it should be `%d-%M-%y` e.g.

```
SELECT  STR_TO_DATE('15-Nov-20', '%d-%M-%y')
```

Output:

```
2020-11-15
```

To then get the year and week, you can use `DATE_FORMAT` with one of `%U`, `%u`, `%V` or `%v` dependent on your needs (see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) for their definitions) e.g.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('15-Nov-20', '%d-%M-%y'), '%Y-%U')
```

Output

```
2020-46
```

Note that if you use `%V` or `%v` for the week number, you must also use `%X` or `%x` for the year e.g.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('15-Nov-20', '%d-%M-%y'), '%X-%V')
```

Output

```
2020-46
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=89b8d43d8b7dbd5524623370a6041c83)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use PHP's DateTime class to get week and year numbers.

```
$parsedDate = new DateTime('15-Nov-20');
$week = $parsedDate->format("W");
echo 'Weeknumber:' . $week;
echo '<br>';
$year = $parsedDate->format("Y");
echo 'Year:' . $year;
```

This will give you:

```
Weeknumber:46
Year:2020
```